# What is the difference between an autonomous system and a dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

[Wikipedia says,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics))

> Autonomous systems are closely related to dynamical systems. Any autonomous system can be transformed into a dynamical system and, using very weak assumptions, a dynamical system can be transformed into an autonomous system.

What is the difference between an autonomous system and a dynamical system?

Comment: again from wiki. its a system with a state and evolution rule.

Comment: I find this quote from wikipedia a bit confusing. There are some subtleties that prevent any autonomous system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ to define a dynamical system. It might be a finite-time blow-up (like in $\dot{x} = x^2$) or a failure of existence-and-uniqueness condition (like in $\dot{x} = x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ -- there are two solutions for each Cauchy problem of form $(x, t) = (0, t^\ast)$). Speaking about this wikipedia entry, they emphasize that autonomous system of differential equations is defined in Euclidean space, whereas dynamical systems may be defined on other topological spaces.

Comment: @Evgeny Interesting. Perhaps you can answer this explaining the difference between the two, and why the wikipedia quote is wrong. A simple definition of the two might be a nice place to start, for me at least.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to do it a little bit later. In short, dynamical systems include flows which in case of Euclidean space correspond to nicely behaving (no finite-time blow-ups, no non-uniqueness) autonomous systems. Not all autonomous systems define a flow, but some of them really could be transformed into dynamical system. I've seen a way to fix the finite-time blow-up, but I don't remember is there a way to fix non-uniqueness of Cauchy problem solutions.